# Praying at Amukah = Finding a mate. Since when?

Tags: history, eretz-yisrael, segulah, shidduchim-dating, provenance

Many people, I'm sure, have heard of the famous *segulah* for finding one's soulmate: praying at the grave of Yonasan ben Uziel in Amukah, Israel.

I'm ***not*** asking if this works, or why it would work, or if this is a valid form of *hishtadlus*, or if *segulos* in general work at all, or how they work.

All I'm asking is for the provenance of this (supposed) *segulah*. How old is it? How did it originate? Does anyone of note mention it?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2143/759

Comment: Sociologists would tell you there's a contemporary trend towards "rituals involving saint-like characters" in Israel; and obviously now that so many more Jews live in Israel it's a more popular site than, say, someplace in the Ukraine. But I don't have more information, sorry.

Comment: What you're really supposed to do is "forget" your siddur/tehilim there, and hope a nice person of the opposite gender finds it and calls you ...

Comment: What you're really supposed to do is creepily hang around Amukah all day waiting for someone of the opposite gender to leave their siddur/tehillim behind and hope they wrote their phone number in the front cover...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://chareidi.org/archives5761/korach/KRfeatures.htm

> While our rabbis tell us that davening at kivrei tzaddikim is a
>   segulah for all types of help, the tradition of Amuka as an address
>   for unmarried men and women is a relatively new one, according to
>   experts in the field. It was "rediscovered" about fifty years ago by
>   Rav Shalom Gefner of Meah Shearim, among many other holy grave sites,
>   which he ferreted out according to the writings of Rav Chaim Vital,
>   based on the teachings of the Arizal.
>
> A well-known famous Tsefati, Hershel the Shamash and Rav Berel Tsfaser
>   knew the location of the tsiyun of Yonoson ben Uziel and told Rav
>   Shalom about it in 1951. There were no roads in the area at that time.
>   Reb Shalom began to come to the tsiyun with groups of young men:
>   braving the elements, traversing dirt paths and scurrying down rocky
>   mountainsides in order to reach it. Some of these adventurous bochurim
>   were of marriageable age, and some became engaged soon after their
>   trek to Amuka, the story goes, for lifum tsa'aro agro. . . And more
>   bochurim made the trip, and more eligible young ladies. . .as roads
>   were paved and access was facilitated.
>
> In a book called, Tovah Ri'iyata from 5734 (1974), it is said in the
>   name of Rav Chaim Lichtenstein (who was niftar in 5725) that, "Prayer
>   at the tsiyun, of Yonoson Ben Uziel is a segulah for shidduchim." This
>   is the earliest written mention of the place being a segulah for
>   shidduchim.
>
> Explanations have been offered ex post facto to explain the segulah.
>   Some say that since Rav Yonoson never married, he helps others find
>   their true mates as a kaporoh, but there seems to be no reason to
>   believe that he in fact remained single.
>
> Some, probably as a joke, use a source in Rashi on Yevomos 17a: "All
>   pisulim that don't find a wife go there." The next Rashi begins "Vehi
>   amuka," referring to the next statement in the gemora.

Answer (score 4):

I was told by my Rebbi in Yerushalayim that the segula was made up in the 1970's by someone named Gafner who worked for Hoffman's tours.

Comment: I guess it became a segulah for Gafner's parnassah.

Comment: That's actually exactly what my Rebbi said!

Answer (score 1):

It is of very recent origin (50 years or less) and stems from some misreading of text, hence no one of note mentions it. I believe Rav Yakov M. Hillel alludes to it as a false 'segulah' in his work ad hagal hazeh. I will try to locate more sources that have debunked this.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/kabala-in-halacha#comment36913_11819