# Segulah for having a boy

Tags: sources-mekorot, sexuality, men-male, segulah, baby-infant

I have heard before that a segulah for having a boy is to have relations with one's wife twice in one night. I remember hearing this in the name of Chazal. Does anyone know the makor for it?

Comment: See my other question related to this here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27203/relations-twice-as-segulah-for-boy-what-about-zugos

Comment: @jake Assuming that having a boy or girl is entirely and equally random, yes.

Comment: @jake You can conclude the odds are 1-(.5^5) only if you assume randomness such that any given couple actually has a 50 percent change of having a boy each time they have a baby. This [may not be medically true](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11692-008-9046-3?LI=true).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2147/759

Comment: @HodofHod No, only if it averages randomly. If God is playing around with who has which gender child (reasonable), He has apparently been doing so in a way that evens out over the whole population, which פוק חזי is basically true.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's spread over a large population, this is talking about one couple.

Comment: @HodofHod Yes...one arbitrary couple in a population. That's how statistics work. For an arbitrary couple in our population with 5 kids, there is 90-something chance for having at least one boy.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question is not talking about picking a couple at random; on a case by case basis, more information is available (e.g. the number of brothers and sisters of the husband).

Comment: @Fred and which case is the question talking about if not the average one?

Comment: @DoubleAA. Probability for (lhavdil) some hereditary disease may be 5% spread throughout the population, but for a family with a history it will be much higher. Similarly jake's _practical_ advice that having 5 children carries a 97% chance of a boy is only true you assume that every individual couple always has a 50:50 chance. Alternatively, if you're speaking of an arbitrary couple about which nothing else can be known (i.e., not practical advice) then yes, statistics would say there is a 50:50 chance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes from Niddah 31b:

> הרוצה לעשות כל בניו זכרים יבעול וישנה
>   – One who wants to make all his children males should cohabit once and then repeat it.

Rashi there explains that this comes in continuation to the previous statement in the Gemora that if the wife emits seed first the child conceived will be a male. By first arousing his wife's desire in the initial act, she will emit seed first the second time.

Comment: Maybe she'll become pregnant the first time around (I saw Rashi and didn't really understand.)

Comment: @Yehoshua Aruch Le'ner there indeed points out that this method is not as reliable as the previous one (delaying his own seed)  because she might conceive the first time round.

Comment: Baruch she'cavanti. However I don't know if it was the Aruch L'Ner that I was m'cavain to or the simple fact that she might conceive the first time around!

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara says that if the husband loves the wife more it will (may?) be a girl. If the wife loves the husband more, then a boy. (By loves more it means, finishes first.)

So the recommendation for a boy is to have relations twice, thus allowing the wife to finish first the second time.

I will try to find the source.

Comment: You wrote "girl" twice. Also, you should probably source this gemara in your own answer.

Comment: @HodofHod Oops! Thanks. I know I should source it, I'm trying to find it. It's apparently not in the same place as Michoel's answer, but they are both basically the same.