# Relations twice as segulah for boy -- What about zugos?

Tags: number, sexuality, maseches-pesachim, danger, maseches-niddah

I had [asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27200/segulah-for-having-a-boy) what is the source for the segulah of having relations twice in order to have a boy. I first asked this in order to obtain a source to better ask this question.

The Gemorah says in Niddah 31b
הרוצה לעשות כל בניו זכרים יבעול וישנה – One who wants to make all his children males should cohabit once and then repeat it.

In the answer to my question, Michoel so nicely brought the following explanation,

> Rashi there explains that this comes in continuation to the previous
>   statement in the Gemora that if the wife emits seed first the child
>   conceived will be a male. By first arousing his wife's desire in the
>   initial act, she will emit seed first the second time.

Howevver the Gemorah in Pesachim Daf 109b says
ולא יעשה צרכיו תרי
That a person shouldn't have relations twice as it is a problem of "zugos". Doing something in "pairs" could lead to some sort of sacana (danger).

Is there a stira between the 2 gemorahs? If so how can it be resolved?

Comment: Do it a third time? Maybe it's someone who doesn't worry about zugos.

Comment: See what Abaye says at the top of the next daf; the B'raisa mean that one should not engage in relations immediately after eating or drinking in pairs.

Comment: @Fred sounds like an answer and seemingly takes care of my question!

Comment: [Rabbi Google](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMD_enAU488AU488&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHMD_enAU488AU488&q=%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94+%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95+%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%99+%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C+%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94&spell=1&sa=X&ei=3UdGUYCKM-ajigf_14DgCQ&ved=0CC4QBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.dGY&fp=6405f5db73465c07&ion=1&biw=1163&bih=802) has a few answers to this

Comment: @Michoel Looks like a good question after all!

Comment: I didn't post any of those results as an answer because after @Fred's comment I don't really understand their question.

Comment: @Michoel I understand. Perhaps not a good question but at least those who also thought to ask it. Even in light of what the gemroah says on the next amud!

Comment: @Yehoshua It should go without saying that our medical knowledge of what causes a person to have a son or a daughter doesn't exactly support Rashi's theory. (It has to do with whether the sperm that fertilizes the egg has an x chromosome or a y chromosome, nothing to do with when the wife "emits seed".) I hope you don't expect putting such segulas into practice to have anything better than a 50/50 chance of working.

Comment: @AL The question wasn't to verify if such a segulah works or how it works or it's medically sound...But, thanks for the comment?

Comment: @Yehoshua I know. It was only tangentially related so I commented. BTW as far as the danger goes, I vaguely recall that doing things in pairs makes one susceptible to witchcraft (if nobody else already mentioned that). Then again the number of witches walking around is probably... 0.

Comment: "The Gemorah says in Niddah 31b הרוצה לעשות כל בניו זכרים יבעול וישנה – One who wants to make all his children males should cohabit once and then repeat it."

Does this apply retroactively to existing children?

Comment: Maybe there is a difference when the second biah happens. If done in one session maybe its considered one,and only if there was a hefsek between the biahs(meaning two sessions in one night) then it would be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe since he has intention in gemara Niddah to achieve a specific outcome by the combination of both times he is boel, it is considered as a 'biah arichtah', whereas in Pesachim he was being 'oseh tzerachav', he did not have a higher motivation so he has done 2 seperate bios.