# If two people daven for each other, who is answered first?

Tags: tefilla

Based on the principle that כל המבקש רחמים על חבירו והוא צריך לאותו דבר הוא נענה תחילה - anyone who davens for someone and he himself needs the same thing, he is answered first - who is answered first if two people daven for each other?

The [Daven For Me](http://davenforme.org/) organization tries to match people like this. If anyone has participated in that program and knows, that would be a good answer. [Because I really like the song: [the song/video that inspired the campaign](http://jewishmusicreport.com/2014/09/10/dovid-gabay-the-letter-daven-for-me-official-music-video/).]

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2147/759

Comment: I've always felt this was not the point being made. If someone has a need & they forego the opportunity to fulfill it through prayer because they were busy praying for someone else, that is a huge deal and this person will be rewarded by getting their own needs answered first. This idea of you pray for me and I'll pray for you does not add up.

Comment: @user6591 DavenForMe provides testimonials that it has worked, but not enough details to answer this. :)

Comment: @Scimonster the song also has a testimonial! Not sure if they got answered specifically because of the given havtacha though. Hashem has many messangers.

Comment: @user6591 the song is fiction afaik.

Comment: @Scimonster even the part where he says he did this trick with his friend? Guess we'll have to ask digidigiGabay.